# DRM not initializing eDP LCD Display

Tags: kernel, display, intel, displayport

I'm having an issue with Ubuntu on a small-form-factor PC I built. It is based on the ASUS Q87T and the Intel G3258 CPU. Everything works great with an external (DP, HDMI, VGA) display, but I cannot get video output from the 4K LCD connected over eDP. I captured a `dmesg | grep drm` of the system booting, when I add `drm.debug=0xe` to the kernel boot flags.
http://pastebin.com/e9ppm31F

When the system powers up, the LCD back-light comes on, and I can control the brightness through the buttons and through /sys.

I can successfully capture an EDID using `get-edid|parse-edid`

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.1. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
1 potential busses found: 7
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 7
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "LQ156D1JX01"
    ModelName "LQ156D1JX01"
    VendorName "SHP"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 5 of 2014
    # EDID version 1.4
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 350 190
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "false"
    Modeline        "Mode 0" 533.25 3840 3888 3920 4000 2160 2163 2168  2222 -hsync -vsync 
EndSection
```

And the output of xrandr is here: http://pastebin.com/yNJpCZ2u

But I simply cannot get any video from the monitor. I soldered a jumper to the LCD control board to activate "Built in self test". That worked perfectly, the whole screen lit up and flashed red-green-blue.

And still no video! I'm unsure of what I should try next. Any suggestions?

(P.S. Sorry if this problem is too specific for this forum, or not related to Ubuntu enough. Suggestions of good places to seek help are welcomed :)